# Compare values of two arrays in python

Tags: python

How can i check if item in `b` is in `a` and the found match item in `a` should not be use in the next matching?

Currently this code will match both 2 in `b`.

```
a = [3,2,5,4]
b = [2,4,2]

for i in b:
  if i in a:
    print "%d is in a" % i
```

This is the required output:

```
2 => 2 is in a
4 => 4 is in a
2 =>
```

**EDIT: Example 2:**

```
a = [3,2,2,4]
b = [2,4,2]
```

output should be

```
2 => 2 is in a
4 => 4 is in a
2 => 2 is in a
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(long post but read it entirely, solution is at the end).

Remove the found value or register it in another dict.

Better though is to count the number of apparitions inside each array and test how many are common.

For the second case, you'd have

- for `a`:

  3 appears 1 times
  2 appears 1 times
  5 appears 1 times
  4 appears 1 times
- for `b`:

  2 appears 2 times
  4 appears 1 times

Keep these values in dictionaries:

```
a_app = {3:1, 2:1, 5:1, 4:1}
b_app = {2:2, 4:1}
```

And now, it is simple:

```
for i in b:
    if a_app.has_key(i) and a_app[i] > 0:
        a_app[i] -= 1
```

The `b_app` dictionary would be used in other case.

Here is a test script I wrote (testing all testcases issued here):

```
def f(a, b):
    a_app = {}
    for i in a:
        if not a_app.has_key(i):
            a_app[i] = 0
        a_app[i] += 1
    print a_app
    for i in b:
        print i, '=>',
        if a_app.has_key(i) and a_app[i] > 0:
            a_app[i] -= 1
            print i, ' is in a',
        print '.'

f([1,1,2],[1,1])
f([3,2,5,4],[2,4,2])
f([3,2,2,4],[2,4,2])
f([3,2,5,4],[2,3,2])
```

And here is the output:

```
$ python 1.py
{1: 2, 2: 1}
1 => 1  is in a .
1 => 1  is in a .
{2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}
2 => 2  is in a .
4 => 4  is in a .
2 => .
{2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1}
2 => 2  is in a .
4 => 4  is in a .
2 => 2  is in a .
{2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}
2 => 2  is in a .
3 => 3  is in a .
2 => .
```

Everything is perfect and no order is lost :)

Edit: Updated with @Avaris's suggestions, this script looks like:

```
import collections

def f(a, b):
    a_app = collections.Counter(a)
    for i in b:
        print i, '=>',
        if i in a_app and a_app[i] > 0:
            a_app[i] -= 1
            print i, ' is in a',
        print '.'
    print ''

f([1,1,2],[1,1])
f([3,2,5,4],[2,4,2])
f([3,2,2,4],[2,4,2])
f([3,2,5,4],[2,3,2])
```

Comment: Nice but loses order of the values found - not sure if that is important.

Comment: Nop, it doesn't loose anything :) See output from tests.

Comment: You should use `i in a_app` instead of `a_app.has_key(i)`. `has_key` is removed in 3.x. And for 2.7+ `collections.Counter` will do nicely for `a_app` or `b_app`.

Comment: `collections.Counter` is available to python v2.7 up.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this:

```
a = [3,2,5,4]
b = [2,4,2]
temp = set(a)
for item in b:
    if item in temp:
        print "{0} is in a".format(item)
        temp.remove(item)
```

The set makes the `x in y` check faster (`O(1)` instead of (worst-case) `O(n)`), and it also can be modified safely without destroying my original `a`.

Comment: fails with `a = [1,1,2], b = [1,1]`

Comment: @MariaZverina: How do you mean? Output is `1 is in a` - what else would you have expected?

Comment: `set` will modify the value of `a`. When my variable `a=[3,2,2,4]` both 2 in `b` should match.

Comment: I guess `1` should be matched twice since `a` has 2 `1`s in it. Depends on what OP wants though.

Comment: @Avaris: Well, he wrote that the found match should not be used again, so if `1` has been matched once, it should not be matched again.

Comment: @Bob: Then you should edit your question to specify your problem correctly. `set()` does not modify the value of `a`, by the way.

Comment: He stated it clearly: he wanted to match each value exactly once even though he had duplicates.

Comment: @Avaris in Maria's comment 1 should match twice.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Isn't it bad to modify a list during an iteration? https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/

Answer (score 3):

Recursive solution:

```
a = [3,2,5,4]
b = [2,4,2]

def find_matches(x, y):
    if y == []:            # nothing more to find
        return
    n = y.pop()
    if n in x:
        print n, "matches"
        x.remove(n)
    find_matches(x, y)

find_matches(list(a), list(b))      # copy the list as they get consumed in process
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the best way to do it, but you could make a list of all matched items and check using that.

```
a= [3, 2, 5, 4]
b= [2, 4, 2]
c= []

for i in b:
    if i in a and i not in c:
        print '%d is in a' % i
        c.append(i)
```

I think looping over a instead of b should solve the problem.

```
a= [3, 2, 2, 4]
b= [2, 4, 2]

for i in a:
    if i in b:
        print i, 'is in a'
```

Obviously `i` is in `a`, but it does solve the problem doesn't it?

Comment: fails with `a = [1,1,2], b = [1,1]`

Comment: Fails? How? It gives the output `1 is an a` And that is the required output

Comment: The output should be given twice, you have two `1`s in `b`.

Comment: Ah, got it. The OP should edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: @elssar yes, already edited. My first example is not that appropriate

Comment: @Bob how about iterating over a instead of b. That should solve the problem, right?

Comment: it will not meet the requirements

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [3,2,5,4]
b = [2,4,2]

hadAlready = {}
for i in b:
    if i in a:
        if not (i in hadAlready):
            print "%d is in a" % i
            hadAlready[i] = 1
```

Comment: fails with `a = [1,1,2], b = [1,1]`